# Send function being called twice

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email, send

I've tried searching the above and found similar results, but non that could fix my issue. I have a WP theme which includes a function to send private messages between users, the receivers get email notification that a private message was received.
The problem is that the message is being sent twice, so is the email. I can see the message in the inbox and outbox twice as well.

here's the code, not sure what's causing the issue:

```
 <?php }

     elseif($third_page == 'send') { ?>
    <?php

        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $uid = $_GET['uid'];

        $user = get_userdata($uid);

        if(!empty($pid))
        {
            $post = get_post($pid);
            $subject = "RE: ".$post->post_title;
        }



        if(isset($_POST['send']))
        {
            $subject = strip_tags(trim($_POST['subject']));
            $message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message']));
            $to = $_POST['to'];

            if(!empty($to))
            {
                $uid = auctionTheme_get_userid_from_username($to);  
            }

            if($uid != false && $current_user->ID != $uid):

            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $myuid = $current_user->ID;

            global $wpdb; $tm = current_time('timestamp',0);        
            $s = "insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."auction_pm (subject, content, datemade, pid, initiator, user) values('$subject','$message','$tm','$pid','$myuid','$uid')";
            //mysql_query($s) or die(mysql_error());        
             // $wpdb->show_errors     = true;
            $wpdb->query($s);
            //echo $wpdb->last_error;
        //-----------------------

            $user = get_userdata($uid);
            AuctionTheme_send_email_on_priv_mess_received($myuid, $uid)

        //-----------------------       
            ?>

            <div class="my_box3">
            <div class="padd10">
             <?php _e('Your message has been sent.','AuctionTheme'); ?>
            </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            elseif($current_user->ID == $uid): 
            ?>

                <div class="error">             
             <?php _e('Cant send messsages to yourself','AuctionTheme'); ?>               
            </div>


            <?php
            else:
            ?>

            <div class="my_box3">
            <div class="padd10">
             <?php _e('The message was not sent. The recipient does not exist.','AuctionTheme'); ?>
            </div>
            </div>


            <?php
            endif;
        }
        else
        {


    ?>   

    <div class="my_box3">
            <div class="padd10">

            <div class="box_title"><?php echo sprintf(__("Send Private Message to: %s","AuctionTheme"), $user->user_login); ?></div>
            <div class="box_content">  
            <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <table>
            <?php if(empty($uid)): ?>
            <tr>
            <td width="140"><?php _e("Send To", "AuctionTheme"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input size="20" name="to" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <tr>
            <td width="140"><?php _e("Subject", "AuctionTheme"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input size="50" name="subject" type="text" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td valign="top"><?php _e("Message", "AuctionTheme"); ?>:</td>
            <td><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <td width="140">&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
            <td width="140">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="send" type="submit" value="<?php _e("Send Message",'AuctionTheme'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </form>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


    <?php } } ?>

</div>
```

I've tried playing around with the last bit of the code by removing/adding the "//", some resulted in emails sent but not messages, some resulted in messages sent 4 times, but none fixed the issue either.

Thanks guys

Comment: Where's the `send` function being called? I don't see any references to that function in your code.

Comment: Sorry, updated the code. Hope enough?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know I've been struggling with the same problem for weeks now and have finally **found the SOLUTION**. 
In my case wordpress was sending an email twice and adding an extra unneeded blank row to the database. I finally found an answer that said it had to do with table or forms or otherwise just **improper html code** wich makes no sense but lo and behold once i **deleted the tables** from surrounding all the php it now works completely fine. I realize that in your case the table makes sense, but still I would highly suggest you try to **rewrite it with divs**. SOme other answers I found with this had to do with improper html and javascript as well as forms or divs not being closed properly. 
However I don't think the problem lies in improper html use, but since i haven't found a case where someone had this problem outside of wordpress it seems that it could be just some **wordpress flaws with tables**, as I checked my code many times and it seemed correct.
Anyway Good Luck, Hopefully that helps.